# combobox SelectedItemChanged fires when XamDataGrid scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I have XamDataGrid in a user control. In the grid I have a Combo box and it has SelectedItemChanged event. I am setting some vales based on the drop down selection. When user selects a row and scroll vertically the SelectedItemChanged event fires and values are setting for that selected line. Is there a way to ignore the event fire.

```
      <igDP:UnboundField Name="HierarchyLevel1" BindingPath="HierarchyLevel1.Value" BindingMode="TwoWay" Label="Hierarchy Level 1"  
                                       DataType="{x:Type proxy:BasicDataDTO}" >
                        <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                            <igDP:FieldSettings EditAsType="{x:Type proxy:BasicDataDTO}" EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}" >
                                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=HierarchyLevel1}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="ValueType" Value="{x:Type proxy:BasicDataDTO}" />
                                        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteRowConverter}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=common_util:GlobalDataCache.BasicDataCache}, Converter={StaticResource CacheConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource HierarchyIdType}}"/>
                                        <EventSetter Event="SelectedItemChanged" Handler="HierarchyLevel_SelectedItemChanged" />
                                        <EventSetter Event="KeyUp" Handler="DdlBasicDataKeyPress"/>
                                        <EventSetter Event="ValueChanged" Handler="DdlBasicDataDes_ValueChanged" />
                                    </Style>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                        </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                    </igDP:UnboundField>
```

Comment: I would imagine that when the user selects a row, the focus is on the dropdownbox, so when they start to scroll, the dropdown is changing values which therefore fires the event, is this event in the view? (not ViewModel) if so, you can invoke the event and take focus of the dropdown. This could be totally wrong but going by your description, I woul say it has something to do with the focus

Comment: its not focus on combo box, its focus on another cell in the grid. It fires for all the rows in the grid.

Comment: Ok, I see, look at this post,

http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/11077 - it might be the bubbling on the routedArgEvent in the event.

Answer (score 0):

I was chasing the same problem.  The solution that worked for me was to add RecordContainerGenerationMode="LazyLoad" to the properties.